Extended vocab huggingface tokenizer merging text into a single string without spaces while decoding
I tried to add new vocab to the existing mistral tokenizer vocab using the add_tokens() method. Everything went fine till I tried the extended vocab tokenizer for decoding the encoded text. I found that in the decoded text, the spaces are completely missing and all the decoded tokens are merged into a single string. Can you please help me resolve this issue. Here's the sample code:
import sentencepiece as spm

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor(model_file='mistral_tok.model')
tokenizer1 = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mistralai/mistral-7b-v0.1")

vocab = [sp.id_to_piece(idx) for idx in range(sp.get_piece_size())]

new_tokens = set(vocab) - set(tokenizer1.vocab.keys())

tokenizer1.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))
# output: 14756

print("After adding new tokens, length of mistral tokenizer:", len(tokenizer1))
# output: 46756

tel_text = "నేను బాగున్నాను. మీరు ఏలా ఉన్నారు?" # original text

mistral_encode_ids = tokenizer1.encode(tel_text)

mistral_decode_text = tokenizer1.decode(mistral_encode_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

print(mistral_decode_text)

# output: నేనుబాగున్నాను.మీరుఏలాఉన్నారు? # decoded text with missing spaces

To dig further into the problem, I re-initialised the mistral tokenizer from its original checkpoint mistralai/mistral-7b-v0.1. Then I added 3 manually defined random tokens to the tokenizer using the same add_tokens method. Now I used the extended vocab tokenizer to encode and decode some text and it worked fine. I mean, the decoded text has retained the spacing similar to the original random text. Here's the code for this experiment:
mistral_tok = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mistralai/mistral-7b-v0.1")

new_tokens = ["yoyoyo", "xoxoxo", "z0z0z0"]

mistral_tok.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

print("After adding new tokens, length of mistral tokenizer:", len(mistral_tok))

random_text = "yoyoyo xoxoxo z0z0z0!"

random_text_2 = "This is my new yoyoyo style xoxoxo of z0z0z0 writing!"

mistral_encode_ids = mistral_tok.encode(random_text)

mistral_decode_text = mistral_tok.decode(mistral_encode_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

mistral_encode_ids_2 = mistral_tok.encode(random_text_2)

mistral_decode_text_2 = mistral_tok.decode(mistral_encode_ids_2, skip_special_tokens=True)

print(mistral_decode_text)
# output: yoyoyo xoxoxo z0z0z0! # decoded text with spacing intact

print(mistral_decode_text_2) 
# This is my new yoyoyo style xoxoxo of z0z0z0 writing! # decoded text with spacing intact

Where is the problem? Why is the extended vocab tokenizer not able to decode properly when using the vocab from a different tokenizer? On the contrary, it is able to decode properly when new tokens are added manually.
